# Singleton thread safe in C# - why to add the double check?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, locking, thread-safety, singleton

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

I don't understand why is the double check ! 
I read that this double check is to solve the  thread concurrency problems - but ...

1. The lock will solve it - so why we need to first 'if'
2. if this singleton will be without the first 'if' it still will be thread safe - right ?
3. if the first 'if' is false - so thread1 will init the 'instance' object => now, the 'instance' is not null and the thread1 is still in the lock block ===>> now, thread2 check the first 'if' and will get false => so he will not get to the 'lock' and imminently will return the instance and thread2 is able to change properties of the 'instance' => so thread1 && thread2 are 'working' on same 'instance' object => so where is the thread safe ... or what I'm missing here.

Comment: I think you got little confused in **3.**

Comment: So I did, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1.The lock will solve it - so why we need to first 'if'

So you won't lock the thred unless you need to create the new instance of the Singleton.
`lock` is a **very expensive operation**, so it's worth doing that extra check.

> 2.if this singleton will be without the first 'if' it still will be thread safe - right ?

Yes, but significantly slower.

> 3.Thread1 && thread2 are 'working' on same 'instance' object => so where is the thread safe

This is the whole point of singleton, only one instance for all threads. That's the thread safe thing...

Comment: But locks are expensive compared to an "if" statement, so leaving the first "if" statement in will ultimately speed your code up.

Comment: @CraigWilson. Just to be sure, you agree with the answer, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that if ThreadA gets interrupted just before the `lock`; ThreadB successfully completes the creation of the singleton then when ThreadA resumes it'll try to recreate the singleton once the lock is released.

Answer (score 0):

the if checks if the singleton is already instantiated if not it create a new instace. and the lock ensure threadsafety.

without the if it would create a new instace on every call (not the idea of singleton). without the lock it would be able that two threads could simulatanusly create a instance, so it would be possible that two instances exists.

if you are only using single threading you can wipe the lock. otherwise (on mt) it's highly recommended to use it.

Comment: The question is why the if check is done twice.  I don't think the OP is suggesting both be removed, or that the lock be entirely removed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good paper from the University of Maryland on why it is recommended (and why it does not always work in modern optimizing compilers)  This is a good read if you have time.

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html